# Remove special characters from string with unicode

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I found the most popular answer to this question is:

```
Regex.Replace(value, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

However, if users type in Non-English name when billing, this method will consider these non- are special characters and remove them.

Is there any way we can build for most of users since my website is multi-language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it Unicode aware:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(value, @"[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+", " ");
```

If you plan to keep only regular digits, keep `[0-9]`.

The regex matches one or more symbols other than Unicode letters (`\p{L}`), diacritics (`\p{M}`) and digits (`\p{N}`).

You might consider `var res = Regex.Replace(value, @"\W+", " ")`, but it will keep `_` since the underscore is a "word" character.

Comment: Shouldn't the "p{N}" be "\p{N}" ?. Also, how would we allow dots (".") to be retained?

Comment: @vdrog Thanks for spotting the old typo. To keep dots just add the dot to the negated character class, `[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}.]+`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my self that the best way to achieve this and make work with all languages is create a string with all banned characters, look this code:

```
    string input = @"heya's #FFFFF , CUL8R M8 how are you?'"; // This is the input string
string regex = @"[!""#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]"; //Banned characters string, add all characters you don´t want to be displayed here.


Match m;

while ((m = Regex.Match(input, regex)) != null)
{
    if (m.Success) 
        input = input.Remove(m.Index, m.Length);
    else // if m.Success is false: break, because while loop can be infinite
        break;
}
input = input.Replace("  ", " ").Replace("  "," "); //if string has two-three-four spaces together change it to one
MessageBox.Show(input);
```

Hope it works!

PS: As others posted here, there are other ways. But I personally prefer that one even though it´s way more code. Choose the one you think better fits for your needing.

Comment: This code can be shortened. `Regex.Replace(input, @"[!""#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_\`{|}~-]+", "")`.